# problems using bootstrap with Angular2 app

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm creating a dynamic website using Angular2 and I am having serious troubles adding bootstrap to it.

my index.html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '"      />');
    </script>
    <title>Angular.io QuickStart</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app/main.js').catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <my-app>Loading App</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

Then I attempt to import it in my app.module.ts file like this:

```
import { NgModule } from 'angular2/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular2/platform-browser';
import { Alert } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
   imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
   declarations: [ AppComponent ],
   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

specifically these lines give a "Module cannot be found" error:

```
import { NgModule } from 'angular2/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular2/platform-browser';
import { Alert } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
```

I am running an Angular2 + ASP.net template installed from the nuGet Package Manager. and I also installed versions of ng2-bootstrap and ng-bootstrap from the Package Manager Console. I also updated my node.js packages and my angular files throughout.

I'm brand new to Angular as a whole and just want to get my base set up so I can start playing with the functionalities.

so what is wrong with my current solution and what can I do to fix it? is there an easier/better way to tie bootstrap to my Angular2 app?

Comment: Consider using angular-cli instead, it's kept up to date by a google team in close contact with the angular team: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: Are you using angularcli?

Comment: *'specifically these line have errors'* - you should probably mention what the errors are.

Comment: @JoeClay editied, thank you.

Comment: @EduardoVargas i just learned about the naming changes mage to angular, i will look into the CLI immediatly

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import if you are including bootstrap in your index.html. You only need to import if you are installing bootstrap using npm install.

Comment: so if i put it in my index.html how do i access/call it in my other files?

Comment: You can just use bootstrap classes and they will work. You don't need to call in ts. BTW you should include bootstrap.js and jquery if you plan on using accordion and other things.

Answer (score 0):

ng2-bootstrap and ng-bootstrap has nothing to do with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) itself. If you are using the CDN, then you can just use the class names as shown in bootstrap examples, there's no need to import anything in `app.module.ts`

Here's a small [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/wTmnP0kZmtibsEbrtfq0?p=preview) of how to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (via [CDN](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn)) in an Angular project.

```
<div class="md-form input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">http://</span>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Domain Name" 
      aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
      [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">

      <span class = "input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" >Calculate</button>
      </span>
</div>
```